# The QR codes in ‘Need for Speed: Rivals’

Tags: need-for-speed-rivals

There are tons of QR codes on cars, locations, videos, and elsewhere in the **world of Need for Speed: Rivals**. The QR codes are always in twisted perspectives that no app on my devices can scan them.

Have anyone else had any luck in scanning these codes? Where do they lead? What do they do?

Comment: Bob422 posted on ea forum yhat qr code goes to need for speed website posting information about their network.  I haven't been able to get them to work yet though.  http://answers.ea.com/t5/Need-for-Speed-Rivals/How-to-scan-a-qr-code-in-ps4-for-need-for-speed-rivals/td-p/1957339

Answer (score -1):

I think that if you can manage to scan them, you get secret paints. If you search "nfs rivals BMW m3 GTS secret paint job,"  you will find an image with a silver BMW with a QR code/ checkerboard pattern on the hood, roof and back of the car.